# trying to get property name to value using for... in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I'm stuck with for loop structure.
I need to get property names of an array of objects,but i am just getting array names and not the properties.can some one help me on this.

```
let employes = [
  {
    name: 'iagor',
    age: 22,
    role: 'front-end developer'
  },
  {
    name: 'jasiel',
    age: 21,
    role: 'illustrator'
  },
  {
    name: 'davi',
    age: 32,
    role: 'movie maker'
  }
];

for (let employe in employes) {
  console.log(`${Object.keys(employes[0])}: ${employes[employe].name}`);
  console.log(`${Object.keys(employes[0])}: ${employes[employe].age}`);
  console.log(`${Object.keys(employes[0])}: ${employes[employe].role}\n`);
}
```

Output:

```
name,age,role: iagor
name,age,role: 22
name,age,role: front-end developer
```

Comment: you get the array's indices by `in` use `for of` loop instead if you have to use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop through array first. You can try like this.

```
for (let employe of employes) {
  for (let key in employe) {
    console.log (key, employe[key]);
  }
  console.log ('\n');
}
```

Comment: i can use this loop in node.js without any problem, right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to first traverse the array .As each element within array is an object you can use object.keys to get the property and value of an item

check this snippet

```js
let employes = [{
  name: 'iagor',
  age: 22,
  role: 'front-end developer'
}, {
  name: 'jasiel',
  age: 21,
  role: 'illustrator'
}, {
  name: 'davi',
  age: 32,
  role: 'movie maker'
}];
employes.forEach(function(employee) {

  Object.keys(employee).forEach(function(item) {
     console.log(item+":" + employee[item]);
    
  });
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
employes.forEach((employ) => {
  Object.keys(employ).forEach((propName) => {
    console.log(`${propName}: ${employ[propName]}`)
  });
});
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please edit your answer to add some explanation.